# Kohana 2.3.4 Admin File Structure

Tags: php, kohana, structure, admin, kohana-2

I'm looking to set up a Kohana 2.3.4 site, and would like to have a shared set of models/config/libraries/helpers, with both the front-end and the admin panel having their own controllers/views.

What would be the best way to set up the file system to create something like this?

Cheers.

---

Quick update:

I've got it working in a hackyish way by setting up:

```
/
application/
- config/
- controllers/
- views/
application_admin/
- config/
- controllers/
- views/
modules/
- shared_code/
- - models/
www_root/
- admin/
- - index.php
- index.php
```

Then the admin/index.php points at ../../application_admin, the public index.php points to ../application, and in config/config.php for both the admin and public, I've enabled the "shared_code" module.

Is there a better way, or any improvements to doing it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solely depends on how you arranged the admin-site. For example, is it a separate module, or just a "namespaced controller" (`controllers/admin/home.php`=> `class Controller_Admin_Home {}`). But as kohana uses the cascaded file system, you can use any class in any place. Assume you have a module `Sandbox` in `modules/sandbox/`, with the model `sand`, located in `modules/sandbox/models/sand`, you could call `$sand_model = new Sand_Model` from anywhere

--- note; this works in kohana 3.x at least, i'm not certain if this applies to the 2.x branch too. But I think you should use 3.x anyway as it's more stable, flexible and has more features you'd definitley want